# Django taking very long time to serve generated static files

Tags: python, django

In my view I generate 5 images (they are generated by pyplot.)

Everything seems to work fine.  The files are generated correctly in the right directory.

But the browser only shows one of the five images, and the requests for the other 4 usually timeout.  Looking at the django server output, the GET requests will often take five minutes to finish.

These images are ~100kb, and are present and correct on the drive immediately after being generated.

Am I missing a call for Django to update the new static files?  Something else?  Please help!

Comment: Not enough informations.

Comment: use nginx to serve static files instead of django

Comment: I'm using django as an interface for a single user in a corporate environment; I would really rather not have to run nginx in order for the user to be able to see five images on a page.

Comment: how are you running the application?

Comment: manage.py runserver - just running and testing on my local machine atm, although in deployment it's in a container.

Answer (score 1):

Deal with them as a media file, save the files to your media server (CDN or local), then send the URL of the images to the browser to load them.

Comment: I've tried this.  Now three files reliably load, but two take a long time.  Very strange.  I may just have to use nginx.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar problem but with audio files. To resolve that issue I used pagination and that solved my issue. I think you should try that, like view one image in one page and second image on second page.

Comment: Thank you, but I wish to see multiple images at once.

Comment: you can add the url of the image to the db and then using object of the model you can access the image in static folder using for loop in html